# Running code only once in a lifecycle react native stateless component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to run my code only once in life cycle. right now i have put my code in useEffects and put a condition on to it but i want to ask is there any way we can write code that runs only once in a lifecycle of component

Answer (score 2):

use [] to run one time

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // Your code
},[])
```

Comment: but use effects with run every time state is change i just want something like a constructor() function that only run once in the beginning. also please explain the purpose of [] in useEffects 

thanks in advance

Comment: [vari] if use like this, once vari value is changes then the useeffect will call. its working like component did update. if you let it empty [] then useeffect will work as component did mount or maybe like constructor